# Lookup available people for a given week and day in google sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, filter, flatten, week-number

So I am looking for a bit of advise on how to solve my task/issue here!

I have a tab called Attendance where there is a list of people and coresponding dates / weeks.
I have another tab called Raid Where I want to see the list of people who are able to attend for Wedensday and another list of people who are able to attend on Thursday, for that coresponding week which are specified in the raid tab.

If someone can not attend, then the name will be marked in the Attendance tab with either a 0 or x or something

I will attach an example sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12Qg3PpwsRZK_ImviNb2u1ibauD8ro4u6Y6vJymnQx30/edit#gid=1332938469

I hope someone with some sheet magic and help me with a solution on how to achieve this!

Comment: only for week 1 ?
or all wednesdays?

Comment: So I would like it to be somewhat dynamic, so if you change in raid Week 1 to Week 10 it would give me attedenance for week 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wednesday:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(FILTER(Attendance!B6:22&Attendance!A6:A22&Attendance!B6:22, 
 ISOWEEKNUM(Attendance!B5:5)=REGEXEXTRACT(D1, "\d+")*1, 
 WEEKDAY(Attendance!B5:5, 2)=3)), 
 "where not Col1 matches 'x.*x|0.*0'", )
```

thursday:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(FILTER(Attendance!B6:22&Attendance!A6:A22&Attendance!B6:22, 
 ISOWEEKNUM(Attendance!B5:5)=REGEXEXTRACT(D1, "\d+")*1, 
 WEEKDAY(Attendance!B5:5, 2)=4)), 
 "where not Col1 matches 'x.*x|0.*0'", )
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate! exactly what I was looking for! I would NEVER have figured that out myself holy